# Having problem loading the entire HTML file once password is entered correct

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, if-statement

I have two HTML files that are to be loaded. One of the files secret.html should load only when the password is correct.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Secrets</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Secrets</h1>
  <form action="/check" method="POST">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="text" id="password" name="password" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**secrets.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Secrets</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Secrets</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>When making chocolate desserts, always add a little salt. It makes the chocolate flavour more intense.</li>
    <li>Whenever you travel abroad bring a new soundtrack for each place you visit, preferably one you have never heard
      before.
      In the future, every time you listen to each soundtrack again they will bring you vivid memories of the places you
      have
      visited.</li>
    <li>Do not try to be the person your parents would want you to be. Be the person you would like your child to be be.
      It more
      clearly
      defines your own convictions, desires, goals, and motivates you to be your best.</li>
    <li>If a friend or a family member gets diagnosed with dementia or alzheimer, in the early stages try to find out
      what their
      favorite songs of all time are. In this way you would be able to create a playlist for them that could be of great
      benefit in the later stages of the disease.</li>
    <li>When a friend is upset, ask them one simple question before saying anything else: 'Do you want to talk about it
      or do
      you want to be distracted from it?'</li>
    <li>If you ever forget your WiFi password or you want to get your school WiFi password etc. Just type this command
      into the
      command line of a computer already connected to that WiFi: netsh wlan show profile WiFi-name key=clear</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js** to get the "post" and "get" from client and to respond accordingly.

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import { dirname } from "path";

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
});
app.post("/check", (req, res) => {
 if (req.body.password === "okcorrect") {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/secret.html");
  }
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

[Incomplete page loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvhnM.png)

**Solution:**

Same code if I add "else statement" it works perfectly fine

```
app.post("/check", (req, res) => {
 if (req.body.password === "okcorrect") {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/secret.html");
  }else{
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");}
});
```

Could someone explain why only partial HTML gets loaded if I don't use the else command

Comment: It really doesn't make sense to try to send two responses to the same request.

Comment: without else it sends two responses when password is success.

Comment: Don't send file, when password is success. Redirect to public or private route according to status.

Comment: Your `if/else` works because you have block scoped the logic. Without it you probably need to do an early return. Try `return res.sendFile`.

Answer (score -2):

The code with else does a different thing.

Without the else you just call again to the server while the 1st call is not yet finished.

With the else you are not calling again at all if you call the 1st time.

Comment: Daniel Thank you for the response. I understand that both responses get executed. But I wanted to understand why only half the html is loaded as shown in image. I was expecting the page to not show anything (get stuck)

Comment: Try to use the development console in the browser while running your tests. In the network tab of the development console, you should see what's being loaded by the browsers while the two calls are made. From here, maybe we can understand what's happening.